# What kind of manifold doesn't have a specific rank distribution?

Tags: differential-geometry

For example, I know that $2$ dimensional sphere doesn't have rank $1$ tangent distribution for it vanishes at some point by the hairy ball theorem. Is there any criterion for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a closed oriented manifold has a distribution of rank $1$ then its Euler class vanishes.

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/38414/euler-characteristic-of-a-manifold-with-non-vanishing-vector-field

Thurston there exists a foliation (integrable distribution) of codimension 1 on a closed manifold if and only if its Euler class vanishes.

https://www.jstor.org/stable/1971047?seq=1